# Showing that a function is not meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Please, I need some advices to solve this exercise:

*Let $f$ be meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$ but no entire. Let $g(z)=e^{f(z)}$. Show that $g$ is not meromorphic on $\mathbb{C}$.*

I appreciate your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Since $g$ is meromorphic but not entire on $\mathbb{C}$, it has a pole, say, at $z_0$. What can you say about the behavior of $g$ near $z_0$?

Comment: I can say that the principal part of the Laurent's series is not vanish. I tried to show that there not exist the limit in two different directions but I can't clarify my ideas.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $f$ has a pole of order $n>0$ at $z$.  Then $f'$ has a pole of order $n+1$ at $z$.

If $g$ has an essential singularity at $z$ we are done.  Since $g$ has an isolated singularity at $z$ we just need to rule out the possibility that $g$ has a pole or removable singularity.

Assume $g$ has a pole of order $m>0$ . Then $g'$ has a pole of order $m+1$.  But it also has a pole of order $m+n+1$ since $g'=f'e^f$.  Hence $n=0$ which is a contradiction.

Assume $g$ is analytic at $z$.  Then $g'$ is analytic, which is impossible since $g'=f'e^f$ and $f'$ has a pole at $z$.

This shows $g$ has an essential singularity everytime $f$ has a pole.  Since $f$ is meromorphic but not entire, $g$ has an essential singularity.

Comment: Well done. Thank you Seth.

Comment: You are welcome!