# How the poles of the function $\exp(f)$ or ($e^{f}$) are characterized?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $z_{0}$ isolated singularities for a function $f$. How do I prove that $z_{0}$ is not a pole for the function $\exp(f)$?

Comment: look at my answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921365/showing-that-a-function-is-not-meromorphic-on-mathbbc/921372#921372

Comment: That covers the case $z_0$ has a pole.  The case $z_0$ has a removable singularity is trivial.  Then you only have the case of an essential singularity.

Comment: The essential singularity case is pretty easy, just use the fact that every annulus has dense image to show $e^f$ would have an essential singularity.

Comment: I might as well make this an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $g=e^f$.

If $f$ has a removable singularity then $g$ does too.

If $f$ has an essential singularity then choose two sequences approaching $z_0$ such that $f$ approaches $0$ and $1$ respectively.  Then $g$ approaches $1$ and $e$ respectively so it must have an essential singularity.

If $f$ has a pole see my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921365/showing-that-a-function-is-not-meromorphic-on-mathbbc/921372#921372) which shows that $g$ has an essential singularity.